# Oracle Apex - Interactive Grid Set Value on Current Row

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a page with an editable interactive grid.
It has 3 columns:

```
ID (read only)
Product (select list)
Result (read only)
```

I have a dynamic action:

```
Event: Change
Type: Region
Region: MyGrid
```

That is trying to update the value of the Result column based on what the user selects on the Status column. So once a Product is selected my action would search for its ID on a different table to fill out the Result column.
Issue is, I don't know how to use current ID for each row. e.g.

```
select result from table_2 where table_2.ID = ???
```

Anyone knows how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Should it not just be ```:ID``` ? if it is a dynamic action on  column change of an IG region, the columns can be passed in as bind variables